# Recode month factor

Tags: r, refactoring, recode

I have a dataset with like this:

```
age month
5    apr
6    jun
7    dec
```

When i write :

```
str(data$month)
```

I have,

```
Factor w/ 10 levels "apr","aug","dec",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
```

And

```
levels(data$month)
 [1] "apr" "aug" "dec" "jul" "jun" "mar" "may" "nov" "oct" "sep"
```

I would like to recode factor to month real month. I tried with:

```
    month<-c("Jan","Feb","Mar",
         "Apr","May","Jun",
         "Jul","Aug","Sep",
         "Oct","Nov","Dec")

data$month<-month[data$month]
data$month<-factor(data$month,levels=month.abb)
```

But when i see my data, may month is equal to jul. How can i do it?

thanks

thanks to @sotos it's works.

```
 library(stringr)
data$month<-str_to_title(data$month)
data$month<-factor(data$month,levels=month.abb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you only need to convert the first letter to upper. There is a function `str_to_title` in `stringr` package that does that, i.e.

```
library(stringr)
str_to_title(c('may', 'jun', 'jul'))
#[1] "May" "Jun" "Jul"
```